# Empty response returned docker flask application

Tags: python, docker, flask

So I have a simple flask application that uses Flask-Script and runs:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

My dockerfile:

```
CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "-h", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I added the -h 0.0.0.0 so it could bind to docker localhost

I then run the docker container with to expost port 5000:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 flask-app
```

This then runs and prints the following which tells me my app is running:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
```

I try to curl on my host but get an empty response error:

```
* Empty reply from server 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I then get a shell into my container and see that my app is listening on the wrong address (should be 0.0.0.0)

```
root@91d7d0e2331c:/app# netstat -tln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here...

Comment: Which OS are your using?

Comment: could you try to use --host? I'm not sure it would change anything, but...

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what -h does here, in the context of flask-script and manage.py it binds to a given localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry just realised that I needed to rebuild the container to use the new commands I added for manage.py runserver.... before I ran

So I did:

```
docker build -t flask-app:latest . -f build/Dockerfile
```

And then proceed to ran and it works fine